# ZMQ, Ratchet, Autobahn -> sometimes slow

Tags: zeromq, autobahn, ratchet

i'm currently experiencing strange behaviour on my website. I'm pushing messages to subscribers via ZMQ, sometimes they receive those messages instantly...sometimes it takes up to like 20 seconds...sometimes not at all.

The website is sitting on a single-core vServer (apache2, ubuntu), might this be the cause?

Users not receiving messages instantly is a huge no-go for us.

Can it be some technical issue? Or is it the server simply not being able to respond fast enough -> get a better server?

Regards

Comment: There's almost no way to diagnose this without (a) seeing some code and (b) having some understanding of your use-case, e.g. what is your message throughput, are your users on the local network or over the internet, etc.

Comment: http://socketo.me/docs/push . That's pretty much the code i'm using. Ofc changes/addition here and there, but nothing fancy..just f.e. a loop for the messages. Users are not on a local network. Sometimes loading things via ajax is also instant ..sometimes it takes a while. I will try to get a dedicated server instead of a virtual one soon and see, if this solves the problem or not.

Comment: hmm... could be the host itself, if you're going over the internet you're subject to garden variety network congestion, and if it's happening frequently then the host could be to blame.  How many simultaneous clients are you pushing to?  I doubt the single-core server is the problem, but perhaps.

Comment: Hm, even when i tried with only 2 clients it made problems. Sometimes ajax requests also take a bit long. I don't know... i hope i can try another server at some point. If the problem still exists then i have to look at what might be causing it.

Comment: If it hits ajax too, sounds like network congestion, or somehow a problem with the network stack on the server.  How much memory on the server?

Comment: i've just migrated to whole website to our other server for testing purposes. sadly couldn't test the websocket pushing, but overall the site was way faster. total time on the current server: about 170ms and 1.30 for db queries. on the dedicated machine it was about 60ms total and maybe 0.40 for db queries.